# MediaPlayer comsume la RAM a pesar de que el Task a finalizado C#

Tags: c#, wpf, task

Estoy intentando hacer un Reproductor *multi-thead* para reproducir muiltiples efectos de sonidos (mouse hover, clic, animaciones, etc...). El reproductor funciona correctamente, pero me doy cuenta de que la **RAM** se estaba llenando cada vez que se reproduce el sonido. Así que decidí establecer un delegado en `audio.BufferingEnded` cerrando el archivo, pero eso no cambió nada.

**Mi código.**

```
Task.Run(() => {

    try
    {
        var audio = new MediaPlayer { Volume = DataHandler.SoundVolume };
        audio.Open(new Uri(GetFullPath(fileName)));
        audio.BufferingEnded += delegate { audio.Close(); };
        audio.Play();
    }
    catch (Exception) { throw; }

}).ContinueWith(async (t) => {

    Console.WriteLine("has finished...");

});
```

La cosa es que necesito un reproductor **multi-thead** para reproducir múltiples efectos de sonido, pero necesito liberar el espacio en memoria después de terminar.

¿Hay alguna forma de liberar el **MediaPlayer** cuando la reproducción haya finalizado?

Si alguien me puede ayudar sería estupendo.

Comment: Revisa: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1573977/is-it-safe-to-call-an-rcw-from-a-finalizer

Answer (score 1):

Mediante la clase "MediaPlayer" de la librería "System.Windows.Media" yo no veo forma de conseguirlo, pero sí que hay otra forma utilizando la clase "WindowsMediaPlayer" de la librería "WMPLib.dll", que está fuera el ámbito del CLR pero parece que es la que [recomienda Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/windows/desktop/wmp/creating-the-windows-media-player-control-programmatically) para integrar en los proyectos de Visual Studio.

La referencia se hace desde la carpeta "C:\Windows\System32\wmp.dll".

Hay que agregar el siguiente espacio de nombres:

```
using WMPLib;
```

Y te dejo una clase de ejemplo que he probado en un proyecto "Windows Forms". He podido comprobar que no hace falta ni siquiera implementar el método asíncrono porque ya lo es el propio que viene en el objeto.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using WMPLib;

namespace WinFormApp
{
    public class WinMedPlayer
    {
        public WindowsMediaPlayer Player { get; set; }

        public void PlayFile(String url)
        {
            Player = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer();
            Player.PlayStateChange +=
                new WMPLib._WMPOCXEvents_PlayStateChangeEventHandler(Player_PlayStateChange);
            Player.MediaError +=
                new WMPLib._WMPOCXEvents_MediaErrorEventHandler(Player_MediaError);
            Player.URL = url;
            Player.controls.play();
        }

        public void Player_PlayStateChange(int NewState)
        {
            if ((WMPLib.WMPPlayState)NewState == WMPLib.WMPPlayState.wmppsStopped)
            {
                this.Close();
            }
        }

        public void Player_MediaError(object pMediaObject)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Cannot play media file.");
            this.Close();
        }

        public void Close()
        {
            if (Player != null)
            {
                Player.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Cuando invoco a la clase lo hago de la siguiente forma:

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        WinMedPlayer wmp = new WinMedPlayer();
        wmp.PlayFile(@"C:\temp\kk\Corto.mp3");

        txtSalida.Text += DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString() + " Ha finalizado la reproducción\r\n";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        txtSalida.Text = ex.Message;
    }
}
```

Ejecutando tres veces el fichero obtengo que libera la memoria cuando finaliza de reproducir el fichero:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si lo ejecuto tres veces seguidas también se puede comprobar que se hace de forma asíncrona y que libera la memoria igualmente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que te sirva como solución.

Saludos.